# How to implement add/remove class to all the <li> except the last one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of `<li>` tags inside a `<ul>` , I have a javascript function that add 'active' class to one of them when clicked and remove it from its siblings , I want to implement this to all except the last `<li>`

```
<ul class='tabs'>
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>About</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
   <li>
     <form>
       <input type='text'/>
        <button></button>
     </form>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The JS function:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li'), function(ele) {
        ele.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            if(ele.nextSibling){
              document.querySelector(".tabs li.active").classList.remove("active");
              ele.classList.add("active");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.

```js
const listItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li'));
const selectableListItems = listItems.slice(0, -1);

selectableListItems.forEach(function(ele) {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if(ele.nextSibling){
          document.querySelector(".tabs li.active").classList.remove("active");
          ele.classList.add("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Or adjust your query selector using a `pseudo-class` in order to select all items except the last one:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li:not(:last-child)');
```